# changing prototype of required React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var Foo = require('Foo');
Foo.prototye.componentDidMount = () => {};
```

I import Foo, but for the case that I use it, I want to override the componentDidMount function on it's prototype. I know this is a hack : (

If I do this, I worry that in other cases where Foo is used, it's prototype will also be changed.

Is there a way to essentially "scope" changing the prototype to within this file?

Comment: yes, though this is in the context of reactjs. updated question to be more clear

Comment: what do you want to do that?

Comment: because I'm essentially 'not allowed' to change the Foo component. But, I want everything about the Foo component, except for it's componentDidMount : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The constructor exists globally. You can, however, make a subclass of Foo if you have access to its constructor. In your example, it seems like a Foo **instance** is being imported, not a constructor, so I'm not sure yet that's an option. But here's what you'd do.

```
function Bar() {
  // ...
}
Bar.prototype = new FooConstructor(); // Must be a separate instance!
Bar.prototype.bar = () => {};
var MyFooExtension = new Bar();
```

EDIT: Forgot, most objects should have a `constructor` property. So you may be able to replace this line:

```
Bar.prototype = new Foo.constructor();
```